# What does @@ mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As I'm browsing through a Rails source code, it contains the line:

```
@@autoloads = {}
```

What does `@@` mean in Ruby?

Comment: just want to add, the general consensus is favor class instance variables over class variables. http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/articles/2006/11/16/use-class-instance-variables-not-class-variables

Comment: Symbolhound is useful for searching for things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to access a class property (a property namespaced to the class), not an instance one (a property that exists for each instantiated object from that class).

In your example, the `@@autoloads` will persist for the length of your program.

```
class TestObj
  @@prop = 0
  def get_prop
      @@prop
  end

  def increment_prop
    @@prop += 1   
  end
end

a = TestObj.new
b = TestObj.new

a.increment_prop 

puts b.get_prop # 1
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/2GoqdGDZ)

Comment: Thank you - I understood that @ were instances variables but am still quite new to Ruby.

Comment: One thing to note is that class variables in a parent class are *not* inherited by child classes. I've known plenty of new Rubyists that were bit by that.

Comment: Class variables are inherited (`@@...`), but class *instance* variables (`@...`) are unique to each class regardless of hierarchy. You'll also get "uninitialized" warnings on the class variables that never happen with instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

@@ identifies a class variable.

Comment: Thanks, Google made finding this answer a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1):

@@ is nothing but indicating a class variable.

A class variable is a variable that is shared amongst all instances of a class. This means that only one variable value exists for all objects instantiated from this class.

Another way of thinking of thinking of class variables is as global variables within the context of a single class.